# Indefinite Integration by Substitution

Tags: integration

I know that when using the substitution method that I must choose an appropriate variable and simplify the function to be integrated. Im wondering if somebody can give me some working and solutions for the following questions so that I can analyse the process to improve my understanding. Im after a little help on this topic:

1. By using the substitution $$u^2=x+2$$,find $$∫(x-2)/√(x+2)  dx.$$
2. A function has $$f' (x)=x^2 (x^3-2)^4 $$ and passes through the point $(1,14/15).$ 
   Find its equation.

Answer (score 0):

$$∫(x-2)/√(x+2)dx = \int \frac {u^2-4}{u}(2udu)$$

The second question is finding $$\int x^2 (x^3-2)^4 dx$$ with the substitution of $$u=(x^3-2)$$ and $$du=3x^2 dx  \implies x^2dx = \frac {1}{3} du $$ $$\int x^2 (x^3-2)^4 dx= \frac {1}{3}\int u^4 du             $$

Comment: Can you elaborate more with the second question working?

Comment: @user694587  Yes, check the edit please.